# Excel dynamically calculate cost of products based on bill of materials (BOM) and purchase price history

Tags: excel, office365, dynamic-arrays, excel-lambda

## EDIT 1 → 2024-03-30:

- Included parameters in the lambda functions so the table names and columns may be injected by the user
- Updated lambda functions with such paramteres
- Even though I found a solution, I tested the whole programming and it's really resource/memmory intensive.

> There must be a way to optimize/simplify it

---

---

### Objective:

Calculate products' costs for a range of dates based on a Bill of Materials and purchase price history of each material (component)

---

### **Process:**

Get products' components and quantities up to the purchase level and then multiply them by their purchase price in each month.

### **Source data**

**TableBOM** has the mix of components needed in each product (Q = qty)

| Componente 1 | Q1 | Componente 2 | Q2 | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Papel 1 | 1 | Tarjeta personal | 20 | Tarjeta x20 |
| Papel 2 | 2 | Tarjetón | 40 | Tarjetón x40 |
| Caja pe | 4 |  |  | Empaque pequeño |
| Cinta pe | 5 |  |  | Empaque pequeño |
| Separador pe | 6 |  |  | Empaque pequeño |
| Tarjeta x20 | 1 | Empaque pequeño | 1 | Tarjeta empaque pe |
| Tarjetón x40 | 1 | Empaque grande | 1 | Tarjetón empaque gr |
| Caja gr | 7 |  |  | Empaque grande |
| Cinta gr | 8 |  |  | Empaque grande |
| Nota | 1 | Empaque pequeño | 1 | Nota empaque pe |
| Tarjeta x20 | 1 | Empaque grande | 1 | Tarjeta empaque gr |
| Tarjetón empaque gr | 1 | Nota empaque pe | 2 | Tarjetón + nota |
| Papel 3 | 3 |  |  | Tarjetón |
| Divi gr | 9 |  |  | Empaque grande |
| Sobre 4 | 1 | Nota sola | 1 | Nota |

**TablePurchaseComponent** has the historical prices of each material (component)

| Fecha | Componente | Precio unitario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/01/2023 | Caja gr | 100 |
| 1/01/2023 | Caja pe | 110 |
| 1/01/2023 | Cinta gr | 120 |
| 1/01/2023 | Cinta pe | 130 |
| 1/01/2023 | Divi gr | 140 |
| 1/01/2023 | Nota sola | 150 |
| 1/01/2023 | Papel 1 | 10 |
| 1/01/2023 | Papel 2 | 20 |
| 1/01/2023 | Papel 3 | 30 |
| 1/01/2023 | Separador pe | 190 |
| 1/01/2023 | Sobre 4 | 200 |
| 1/01/2023 | Tarjeta personal | 2 |
| 1/01/2024 | Caja gr | 200 |
| 1/01/2024 | Caja pe | 220 |
| 1/01/2024 | Cinta gr | 240 |
| 1/01/2024 | Cinta pe | 260 |
| 1/01/2024 | Divi gr | 280 |
| 1/01/2024 | Nota sola | 300 |
| 1/01/2024 | Papel 1 | 20 |
| 1/01/2024 | Papel 2 | 40 |
| 1/01/2024 | Papel 3 | 60 |
| 1/01/2024 | Separador pe | 380 |
| 1/01/2024 | Sobre 4 | 400 |
| 1/01/2024 | Tarjeta personal | 4 |

Tables in the sheet:

[image]

---

### **Lambda functions (as defined names):**

**fxProcessVal:**

Parameters → `lookup_val;component1_cols;component2_cols;result_col`

Code:

```
=LET(
    comp_res; VSTACK(
        FILTER(component1_cols; result_col = lookup_val);
        FILTER(component2_cols; result_col = lookup_val)
    );
    comp_res_fil; FILTER(comp_res; CHOOSECOLS(comp_res; 2) <> "");
    lookup_col; IFNA(EXPAND(lookup_val; ROWS(comp_res_fil)); lookup_val);
    IFERROR(HSTACK(lookup_col; comp_res_fil); "")
)
```

**fxProcessCompRow:**

Parameters → `data;lookup_row;component1_cols;component2_cols;result_col`

Code:

```
=LET(
    sourceData; fxProcessVal(
        INDEX(data; lookup_row; 2);
        component1_cols;
        component2_cols;
        result_col
    );
    res_val; INDEX(data; 1; 1);
    res_col; IFNA(EXPAND(res_val; ROWS(sourceData)); res_val);
    sourceRes; HSTACK(res_col; DROP(sourceData; 0; 1));
    IF(
        sourceData <> "";
        FILTER(sourceRes; CHOOSECOLS(sourceRes; 2) <> "");
        CHOOSEROWS(data; lookup_row)
    )
)
```

**fxProcessComp:**

Parameters → `source;component1_cols;component2_cols;result_col`

Code:

```
=LET(
    seq; SEQUENCE(ROWS(source));
    reducer; REDUCE(
        "";
        seq;
        LAMBDA(acc; curr;
            VSTACK(
                acc;
                IFNA(
                    fxProcessCompRow(source; curr; component1_cols; component2_cols; result_col);
                    HSTACK(""; ""; "")
                )
            )
        )
    );
    temp_res; DROP(reducer; 1);
    temp_res
)
```

**fxCompCost:**

Parameters → `component1_cols;component2_cols;result_col`

Code:

```
=IFNA(
    INDEX(
        unitprice_col;
        MATCH(
            MAXIFS(purchasedate_col; purchasedate_col; "<=" & date; purchasecomponent_col; comp) &
                comp;
            purchasedate_col & purchasecomponent_col;
            0
        )
    );
    0
)
```

**prox:**

Parameters → `seed;component1_cols;component2_cols;result_col`

Code:

```
=LET(
    res; IF(
        COUNTA(seed) = 1;
        fxProcessVal(seed; component1_cols; component2_cols; result_col);
        fxProcessComp(seed; component1_cols; component2_cols; result_col)
    );
    comp; CONCAT(seed) = CONCAT(res);
    IF(comp; seed; prox(res; component1_cols; component2_cols; result_col))
)
```

---

Reference:

[image]

### Formulas

Formula to explode the BOM list (and desaggregate each product material and quantity needed):

```
=UNIQUE(DROP(REDUCE("";TableBOM[Resultado];LAMBDA(acc;curr;VSTACK(acc;prox(curr;TableBOM[[Componente 1]:[Q1]];TableBOM[[Componente 2]:[Q2]];TableBOM[Resultado]))));1))
```

[image]

The dates to calculate the costs of each product are dynamically set in a range using this formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Q1);SEQUENCE(1;DATEDIF(Q1;Q2;"M")+1;MONTH(Q1);1);1)
```

[image]

## STUCKED HERE:

I would like to set Q3 (dates range as a spilled range) and calculate the cost for each product in each month.

Currently the SUMPRODUCT calculates the total for all the months (dates in the range).

I've tried BYCOL and a combination of MAP and Sequence but haven't figure it out.

Any help I would appreciate it.

[Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7w1sQerWmJeBduNhgrjQ?e=qXhQsL) to read-only sample file (no macros)

```
=LET(
     data;L4#;
     date;Q3#;
     res;INDEX(data;;1);
     comp;INDEX(data;;2);
     q;INDEX(data;;3);
     lab;UNIQUE(res);
     cost;q*fxCompCost(comp;date);
     rt;MAP(lab;LAMBDA(a; SUMPRODUCT((res=a)*cost)));
     temp;HSTACK(lab;rt);
temp
)
```

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Do you actually want a single formula for `P22:AN33`?

Comment: Exactly. To output the labels and the costs for each month.

Comment: A plus would be to also input the dates' range as variables in the formula

Comment: Look into using `MAKEARRAY()` that will be the fix as far I see.

Comment: Will do. Thanks mayukh

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of `REDUCE` and `SEQUENCE` to iterate through each date column.

```
=LET(
     data;L4#;
     dateRow;DATE(YEAR(ParamStartDate);SEQUENCE(1;DATEDIF(ParamStartDate;ParamEndDate;"M")+1;MONTH(ParamStartDate);1);1);
     headers;HSTACK("";dateRow);
     date;dateRow;
     res;INDEX(data;;1);
     comp;INDEX(data;;2);
     q;INDEX(data;;3);
     lab;UNIQUE(res);
     cost;q*fxCompCost(comp;date);
     reducer;REDUCE("";SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(date));LAMBDA(acc;curr;HSTACK(acc;MAP(lab;LAMBDA(a; SUMPRODUCT((res=a)*CHOOSECOLS(cost;curr)))))));
     result;VSTACK(headers;HSTACK(lab;DROP(reducer;;1)));
     result
)
```

Names added to the worksheet:

ParamStartDate: `Q2`
ParamEndDate: `Q3`

Final:

[image]

If someone comes up with a better solution even to process the BOM please post it.

Hope this helps somebody else.